# Add MathJax rendering to chat on all MathJax sites

Tags: feature-request, chat, mathjax

In StackExchange sites that support MathJax the inline markup is rendered in comments but not chat rooms -- at least I noticed this is the case on https://stats.stackexchange.com/.  This is awkward, particularly for comment discussions that are moved to chat.